# Adding <div> in middle of ng-repeat using $index - Bootsrap container

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am tring to output `<div>` in middle of `ng-repeat` using `$index==` - however the Banner `<div>` is within the parent `container` so its not going accross the full width of the screen. I have tried using the `class="container-fluid"` on the Banner, but its making it even smaller. Is there any way to break out of the parent container at all (just for that one div, in the middle of the `ng-repeat`) to make the Banner full width?

This is how I would like it to look (for visual purposes only, need div's to be output using the ng-repeat): [Plunker-1](https://plnkr.co/edit/vEF8vu1WMVVXTammr50o?p=preview)

And this is how it currently looks: [Plunker-2](https://plnkr.co/edit/vA9sOdvGhuUNQ3nqvQFc?p=preview)

Comment: the <div> which have class "container-fluid" is creating alignment problem, as its putting left and right margin. So you can remove this class or wrtie custome class to remove left and right margin

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution : https://plnkr.co/edit/pYO1G8M3jIDXHrRSE4YE?p=preview

---

You do not need container-fluid to achieve what you intend to.

---

```
 <div class="col-md-12" id="Banner" ng-if="$index==8">

               <div class="well well-sm text-center">
                  Banner

              </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but thats still only going as far as the edges of the parent `container` div. I need it to go across the whole page - see `Plunker-1`

Comment: Plunker-1 and my plunker both show the same result to me.

Comment: @JamesP: see your point. With the same technique of Agarwal, may you do the same? Just print the first half of items in one group first, then the banner, then the second half?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, try this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">

  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div ng-class="$index === 8 ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-3'" ng-repeat="item in Data">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="Banner" ng-if="$index === 8">
        <div class="well well-sm text-center">
          Banner
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="well active" ng-if="$index !== 8">
        <h3>{{item}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about one like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/ERe8iK?p=preview) one?

What I've done was to make the `.well` absolute positioned, so you can "bypass" normal document flow, making the `.banner` as long as you like, thus adding extra width with percentage values (so you can have it a bit fluid on resizing).

```
.banner{
  position: absolute;
  width: 104%;
  right: -2%;
}
```

So, you get your banner wider, more than 100% (which is the container's width). In order to get it in the middle subtract half of extra width (4% / 2 == 2%) from the right (or could add 2% from the left).

Problem is the responsiveness, as it breaks for some breakpoints. I would suggest go with a solution like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and CSS3 `calc()`, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), to tackle this one.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in Data">
  <div class="col-md-12 well well-sm text-center" 
       id="Banner" 
       ng-if="$index==8">
    Banner
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="well active">
      <h3>{{item}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```